# Drawing PieChart using js

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I need help in drawing a Pie Chart using JavaScript. I'm using Ajax to get my data and to fetch them properly inside a pie chart in my dashboard. Please keep in mind I'm getting my data using Ajax .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please keep in mind for future questions that you should post what you have tried and what your specific problem is. This should also be shown in a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help other users understand your problem and answer you sufficiently.

Comment: Also if my answer does not work for you leave a comment and I will see if I can edit it to help

Comment: thanks @Dan i really appreciate it ! i worked , but if you can just edit your code with some comments please so i know what's going on . thank you

Comment: Of course. Give me 2 minutes

Comment: Bro let's say im getting nb of males and females from db and im drawing it.

Comment: I added an example for you at the bottom. You would sub in your code for getting a value from a database in the getter methods for boys and girls

Comment: Also if this answer is sufficiently correct would you please mark it accepted by using the tick on the left? If not leave another comment :)

Comment: it worked bro , but im still trying to know how do i write male/female inside each circle

Comment: Try something similar to this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/n6f59bd1/3/). I do regret that I have no idea how to automate for different size sectors. I just positioned manually using the methods described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_filltext.asp). Perhaps if you don't figure it out ask another question. I'm sure someone will be able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example of what you could do. You can use methods relating to `Paths` in `JavaScript` and obviously, adapt the code to use values from your `Ajax` files to include an accurate, up to date representation of your pie chart.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function toRadians(deg) {
    return deg * Math.PI / 180 //Converts degrees into radians
}

function startTop(deg) {
    return toRadians(deg - 90); //Positions 0deg at the top of the circle instead of the left or east of the circle
}

var cx = 100; //Centre of the circle, x co-ord
var cy = 75; //Centre of the circle, y co-ord
var radius = 50; //Radius of the circle

ctx.beginPath(); //Begins drawing the path. See link in "Edit" section
ctx.moveTo(cx,cy); //Moves the beginning position to cx, cy (100, 75)
ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, startTop(0), startTop(50)); // ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterclockwise (optional));
ctx.lineTo(cx,cy); //Draws lines from the ends of the arc to cx and cy
ctx.closePath(); //Finishes drawing the path
ctx.fill(); //Actually draws the shape (and fills)
//Can use ctx.stroke() if you just want the border

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#c82124"; //Changes the color
ctx.moveTo(cx,cy);
ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius, startTop(50),startTop(168));
ctx.lineTo(cx,cy);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#3370d4";
ctx.moveTo(cx,cy);
ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius, startTop(168),startTop(360));
ctx.lineTo(cx,cy);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

**Edit**
See path methods

1. [beginPath()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_beginpath.asp)
2. [closePath()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_closepath.asp)
3. [arc()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_arc.asp)
4. [moveTo()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_moveto.asp)
5. [lineTo](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_lineto.asp)
6. [fill()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fill.asp)
7. [stroke()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_stroke.asp)
8. [fillStyle()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_fillstyle.asp)

**Edit 2**
Although I am not familiar with `Ajax` you could do something similar to this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n6f59bd1/2/)

Comment: Thanks bro !! @Dan